# SQL Find min of two datetime values a,b when b can be null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm writing an expression in a Transact SQL query to find the per-record minimum of two datetimes a,b where a cannot be null but b can be null (in which case return a).

I have the following, which I think is correct, and might even be efficient, but is certainly ugly.

Can we do better?

```
case when b is null then a else (case when b < a then b else a end) end as min_datetime
```

Comment: Please untag as possible dupe - the questions are not the same

Comment: I think they are pretty similar, but untagged for now since this has attracted answers and effort by people answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this with a lateral join.  The correct syntax is:

```
select t.*, v.min_dte
from t cross apply
     (select min(v.dte) as min_dte
      from values ( (t.a), (t.b) ) v(dte)
     ) v;
```

This is very handy as the number of values gets larger.  However, the performance is likely to be slightly worse (but not much worse) than a single expression.

As for a single expression, I would go for:

```
case when b is null or a < b then a else b end as min_datetime
```

The performance of this should be essentially the same as your expression.  I find this version simpler.

Comment: Actually, @Gordon Linoff, it's missing an OR, I think:

select (case when b is null OR a < b then a else b end)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `ISNULL` to force a default maximum value.

```
CASE WHEN A < ISNULL(B, '2099-01-01') THEN A ELSE B END AS min_datetime
```

Comment: Not sure on the logic on this : Let say A is 2000-01-01 and B is null, so it compares A to 1900-01-01 - and A is not less, so it outputs B (the null)? If it was ISNULL(B,'2999-01-01') it would seem to work better - trying to see if I have processed it wrong mentally.

Comment: @Andrew nicely spotted. 1900 would be if we were trying to find the maximum between the 2.

Comment: A = 1900-01-01, B IS NULL - Result NULL, After edit A = '2100-01-01' B IS NULL - result NULL

Comment: I understand the answer.  But why would an answer that has a "magic" value be upvoted when that is not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(Val)
FROM Table  a
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES (a.a),(a.b)
) x(Val)
```

Comment: Littleexplanation would help understanding answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(IIF(@a > @b, @b, @a), @a, @b ) as 'Minimum date'
```

**IIF(@a > @b, @b, @a)** will return the min date between the two. If one of the dates will be null then it will return null.

**COALESCE** will take care of returning the first not null value.

Comment: Something to note : IIF is available on 2012 onwards.

Comment: Yes. IIF only exists in MDX. It is not available in Plain T-SQL. Thanks @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(b, '1900-01-01')> a THEN ISNULL(b, '1900-01-01') ELSE a END
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do it

```
min(isnull(b,a))
```

Comment: when b Is not null always b minimum?

Comment: @paparazzo That would give the min across the whole table, but I'm looking for the min per record

Comment: @RobB Then I am looking for a better written question.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.